# Обмен данными между приложениями на c#

Tags: c#

Как реализовать обмен данными между приложениями на c#? Передача будет осуществляться через интернет. Первое приложение будет отправлять авторизационные данные, а второе будет их обрабатывать и посылать ответы и какую-либо другую информацию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сокеты, если совсем низко, ну или WCF, например.

Comment: Пожалуйста, если есть возможность, напишите, где можно взять информацию про сокеты. А то все как-то размыто везде пишут.

Comment: Вот вроде не мудрено написано - http://www.professorweb.ru/my/csharp/web/level3/3_1.php

Comment: Хороша статейка! Спасибо!